# android with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I create a hello world app for android by following this [tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

But once I test this on the real android phone, I got this error message in logcat in eclipse:

```
 sqlitelog (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
 sqlitelog (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) -
```

Anybody experiencing the same?

I created and tested it on device with jellybean.

Comment: Are you able to see that file in your debugger? - this type of problem can occur if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Take care with the version of cordova you're adding to build path and the js you're adding to the HTML. Versions must be the same, maybe downloading last cordova version you'll get rid of the problem